# How to verify C11 compiler support

Tags: 19.10, raspberrypi, compiler

64-bit Ubuntu 19.10.1 is installed on a rPi3.  A C11 compiler is required per [compiling instructions](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/linux/document/compile-source-code.aspx).

What command line test can be performed to verify the compiler supports C11 standards?

I am not certain that gcc is the compiler invoked by the instructions:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/DocumentServer/core/Common/3dParty$ gcc -v
```

returns:

> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
>   Target: aarch64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
>   --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu Thread model: 
>   posix gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)

Comment: Why do you need to *verify* that it behaves according to C11? [Here's a status of C11 support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status).

Comment: It's not clear to me which compiler is used in the instructions.

Comment: They don't mention any special compiler, so you can assume it's gcc, and as Ubuntu 14.04 is supported, you can assume that newer versions are (at least) as C11 compliant. I would try to compile it. If it throws any errors, look into it. If it's *not* gcc your guide would probably mention installing the compiler. Read the `Makefile` for details.